# web2py send uploaded file like email attachment

Tags: python, email, web2py

I
i've done an app in web2py to store FAQ and that give me the possibility to send those FAQ via EMAIL, i'd like to send (when i got that) also an attachment that i upload in the FAQ that i create.

I'v got this in my DB:

```
db.define_table('faq',
   Field('tipo',db.tipo_faq),
   Field('sotto_categoria',db.sotto_categoria_faq),
   Field('oggetto', requires = (IS_UPPER(), IS_NOT_EMPTY())),
   Field('testo_faq',type='text',requires = (IS_UPPER(), IS_NOT_EMPTY())),
   Field('note',type='text',requires = IS_UPPER()),
   Field('faq_ok', type= 'boolean', default = False),
   Field('faq_verifica', type= 'boolean', default = False),
   Field('data_caricamento',type='datetime', writable = False, readable = False, default=request.now, requires=IS_DATETIME(timezone=pytz.timezone("Europe/Gibraltar"))),
   Field('allegato',type='upload', uploadfield = 'nome_file', uploadfolder= allegati),
   Field('nome_file','blob'),
   Field('firma',type='text',readable = False, writable = False,
         default = '<p align="right" style = "font-size:12px">Sistema automatizzato F.A.Q si prega di non rispondere al presente messaggio.<br />Grazie.<br /> </p> <p align="right" style = "font-size:12px"> Per richiedere assistenza <a  href="https://gestionale.porsennasrl.it:81/ASSISTENZA-PA ">CLICCARE QUI</a> </p><p align="right" style = "font-size:12px">HELP DESK PORSENNA SRL</p>'),
    format='%(oggetto)s')
```

and this in my controller:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def prova_invio():
    mail = Mail()
    mail = auth.settings.mailer
    mail.settings.server = 'logging' if request.is_local else myconf.get('smtp.server')
    mail.settings.sender = myconf.get('smtp.sender')
    mail.settings.login = myconf.get('smtp.login')
    mail.settings.tls = myconf.get('smtp.tls') or False
    mail.settings.ssl = myconf.get('smtp.ssl') or False
    faq= db.faq(request.vars.id)
    testo= "<html>"+(faq.testo_faq)+"</html>" + "<html>"+(faq.firma)+"</html>"

    if mail.send(to=request.vars.email,
                subject= faq.oggetto,
                message= testo,
                attachments = mail.Attachment("/home/www-data/web2py/applications/DBurbi/allegati/"+faq.allegato)):
                status = 'RIUSCITO'

    else:
                status = 'FALLITO'
    return dict(status=status,indirizzo=request.vars.email,oggetto=faq.oggetto)
```

when i send the email i got this error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/home/www-data/web2py/applications/DBurbi/static/faq.allegato.abb2396f642c3279.706172746e65722e6a7067.jpg'

I lerned that the name of the file isn't that one, so how can i store the real name of the attachment so i can send it?
And how can i send the attachment only if "there is one" and send email also if there isn't any attachment?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would not specify both `uploadfield` and `uploadfolder` -- the first is for storing files in a blob field within the database, and the second is for specifying a filesystem folder in which to store files. Pick one or the other (since you have specified `uploadfield`, that takes precedence, so files are being stored in the database, not the filesystem).

Note, rather than passing a file path to `mail.Attachement`, you can instead pass an open file object as the first argument along with a "filename" argument. To get the file object and filename, you can do the following:

```
if faq.allegato:
    filename, stream = db.faq.allegato.retrieve(faq.allegato)
    attachment = mail.Attachment(stream, filename=filename)
else:
    attachment = None
```

Then do:

```
mail.send(..., attachments=attachment)
```

Note, the above will work whether the files are stored in the database or on the filesystem.