# How to attach an uploaded file for e-mailing in web2py

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

All,

Python and web2py newbie here - I am trying to forward user input (e-mail address and a file) via e-mail, once a user has uploaded the information on a website. 
The user-provided-information is stored in a database but it is yet over my head to fetch the file from the database and forward it via e-mail. Any pointers much appreciated!

This is my controller action-

```
def careers():
    form = SQLFORM(db.cv_1, formstyle='bootstrap3_stacked')
    for label in form.elements('label'):
        label["_style"] = "display:none;"
    form.custom.submit.attributes['_value'] = 'Submit CV'
    if form.process().accepted:
        applicant = str(form.vars.email)
        mail.send(to=['email@company.com'], message= applicant + ' new CV', subject='CV submission', attachment=mail.Attachment('/path/to/file'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

This is the database model

```
db.define_table('cv_1', Field('email',
requires=IS_EMAIL(error_message='Please provide your e-mail'),
widget=widget(_placeholder='Your e-mail (required)',_readonly=False)),
Field('cv', 'upload', autodelete=True, requires=[IS_LENGTH(1048576,1024),
IS_UPLOAD_FILENAME(extension='pdf')]))
```

Comment: Sorry - just found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718522/web2py-send-uploaded-file-like-email-attachment which should provide a way. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformed filename of the uploaded file will be in `form.vars.cv` (this is the value stored in the `db.cv_1.cv` field in the database). You can use that along with the field's `.retrieve` method to get either the full file path or the file object itself:

```
original_filename, filepath = db.cv_1.cv.retrieve(form.vars.cv)
mail.send(to=['email@company.com'], message=applicant + ' new CV',
          subject='CV submission',
          attachment=mail.Attachment(filepath, original_filename))
```

Comment: Many thanks Anthony! I do get an 'Missing attachment name' error with this. I haven;t found much re this error, so I assume I am missing something rather trivial here...

Comment: Ok - working now! It worked by calling mail.Attachment(filepath, original_filename)). Before I called it with just (filepath) and kept receiving an Missing attachment name error. Thanks again Anthony - much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what's going on, as when the first argument is a string, the code should automatically extract the filename from it. In any case, it is probably better to provide the original filename, as the filename extracted from the path would be the transformed name and not the original. I have updated the answer accordingly.